# python-social-auth creates an additional user account without uid and email address

Tags: django, google-oauth, python-social-auth

I am using python-social-auth to allow users to log in using their social accounts.
I went to admin just recently to see the accounts and I noticed there's an account there that has some randomly generated username. It doesn't have any email, first name or last name associated with it. In the usersocialauth it doesn't have an uid associated with it either. I was wondering where did this account appear from?

Here are the current settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
    'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect',
)

GOOGLE_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS = ['email']
```

I also have the keys for the google backend specified too, of course. I was wondering where is this account coming from and should I keep it?